# Three.js | Apply matrixAutoUpdate = false to all of mesh in the scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a scene that has a lot of OBJ meshes and I want to disable matrixAutoUpdate for all of them. The OBJ objects contain lots of children meshes and I don't know how can I achieve this. Could anyone please help? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the scene graph -- or any root object and its children -- using a patten like so:

```
scene.traverse( function( node ) { // or myObject.traverse(

    // your code here

    if ( node.isMesh ) {

        node.matrixAutoUpdate = false;

    }

} );
```

three.js r.87